# knowing as a noun

Tags: nouns, adjectives

I'm slightly confused by using the word 'knowing' as a noun. Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English (5th edition) says that 'knowing' can be used only as an adjective. But, for example, Merriam-Webster Dictionary says that it can be a noun. I've always thought that we should use 'knowledge' instead of 'knowing', and that the last one doesn't exist as a noun at all. But recently I faced with such Richard Feynman's quote: "I learned very early the difference between knowing the name of something and knowing something". So, is using the word 'knowing' as a noun good and common for standard English?

Comment: Maybe these articles [here](http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-gerunds_1.htm) and [here](http://www.edufind.com/english/grammar/gerund.php) will help you understand the use of the gerund as a noun

Comment: In addition, 'knowledge' and 'knowing' are rarely interchangeable. Look up examples of usages in a good dictionary.

Comment: Thanks, fluffy. I've never thought that stative verb 'know' can be used in progressive form as gerund. But it seems that it can. I'm digging deeper.

Comment: You will likely discover that there is no verb that forbids an *-ing* form — defecting modals notwithstanding.

Comment: Thanks, Edwin. Could you advise me a dictionary better than Longman's one?

Comment: Just because it does not list every gerund separately, does not mean it is a bad dictionary.  It is to be understood (as tchrist says) that all verbs can be gerundicized.

Comment: There are lots of examples of usages of _knowledge_ at http://www.thefreedictionary.com/knowledge and http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/knowledge . You may have to access the OED for examples of the nounal usage of the -_ing_ form  _knowing_. I'd say it is usually used more specifically - having both verbal and nounal properties is useful: _Knowing French is important. Knowing how to ride a bike is useful. Knowing the name of something is not really knowing something. Knowing about Jo is not knowing Jo._ If the OED is hard for you to access, just have a look at these things on Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the sentence given in the question is a simple use of a gerund.

Nevertheless, the *Oxford English Dictionary* lists five different historical meanings for the word 'knowing' used as an independent noun with a separate sense.  Most are obsolete.  One is the use of 'knowing' for 'knowledge,' (as in phrases like carnal knowing), though that usage is pretty rare nowadays.

Another idiomatic sense is still sometimes encountered in phrases like "there is no knowing," e.g., "There's no knowing what he might do if he found out."  This idiom apparently comes from an archaic sense where 'knowing' refers to being informed or aware of something, usually associated in older texts in phrases like "the knowing of X."

In short, aside from a few idioms, 'knowing' is usually only used as a gerund in modern English, with the same meaning as the verb.

Comment: You can tell that both instances of _knowing_ in Feynman's quotation are [gerunds](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/gerund.html) (instead of nouns) because they both have direct objects (*knowing **the name of something*** and *knowing **something***). Nouns do not have direct objects.